# Strategies for battling iOS in-app purchase piracy?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, piracy-prevention, piracy

My app uses in-app purchase, and I verify the transaction receipts with Apple. This has shown me that many users are trying to pirate the in-app purchase mechanism by submitting fake transaction receipts, which come up with a product ID of `com.zeptolab.ctrbonus.superpower1` (from "Cut the Rope"). Of course I don't let them use the in-app purchase items with a fake receipt. What are some strategies for battling iOS piracy and trying to get these people either to pay or to suffer?

Comment: Suffer, haha. You're probably best not to loose sleep over it.

Comment: I was led to this post because I have noticed occurrences of fake purchase receipts with the same SKU.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to truly prevent this is to control everything through your own server(s). Even the infamous "com.zeptolab.ctrbonus.superpower1" receipt is an actual valid receipt that Apple's own validation endpoint will tell you is OK. Once a transaction is completed, the app should send the transaction data to a server you control and:

1. [Validate the receipt with Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html) from your own server.
2. If Apple says it's OK, parse the product_id field from Apple's response and make sure it's a product ID from your app.
3. If the first two items pass, return data to tell your app where to download your content (if it's hosted content).

Even this has a flaw, especially if your IAP content is simply on the device but "locked". There are ways to redirect the validation call from your server to make your app think your server said "everything is OK!". This is much more difficult if your IAP content is hosted remotely as they can't as easily spoof the response with the location of the content if they don't know where the content is in the first place.

The problem in all of this for most people is that controlling your own servers and remote content can get costly, not to mention the need to write your own validation logic. The more difficult you make it for these hacks to be successful, the more it can cost you, so you have to weigh just how much you want to make them "suffer" with how much time, effort and money you're willing to spend vs how much you're making and/or losing. Remember, one "pirated" IAP is not necessarily equal to one lost sale, so it can be hard to gauge just how much you might be losing from this.

Comment: If the response from my server is cryptographically signed, then they can't redirect, because the signature would not validate (without disassembling and modifying the application, but that can just as easily disable the purchase check itself).